# Make a function that even if the user closes the window it would still run

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, next.js

I'm working on a project in React. I have to execute a function that uses a web socket and it would every second retrieve the data. The problem is that I have to find a way so when the user closes the window this function with web socket subscription keeps running.
I tried a serverless function but the problem is that I did not know if I could use a web socket connection in it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to serve your react project via a server,  maybe **express.js**
and you'll need to configure websocket also on the server side then write the function you want here

```
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    
    // Write your function that you want it to be executed
    // after the window is closed here ..
  
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).